# Autocompletion doesn't work without semicolon

Tags: swift, xcode9.2

First I thought Xcode is buggy so I restarted Xcode, but the problem stayed even after rebooting the mac.
I then figured out, that a semicolon after `.default` or the declaration of another variable fixes it.

I think Xcode thinks the assignment isn't over after `.default`, but I'm curious if there is more to it / a better explanation why that is.

```
func setupNotificationHandling() {

    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default

    // Can't access notificationCenter via autocompletion here
}
```

Comment: Confirmed, also happens in Xcode 9.3 beta. Looks like a bug to me. Apparently Xcode offers only methods that can be called on `NotificationCenter.default` – as if you had typed a dot after it.